# The R console is in my native language, how can I set R to English?

Tags: windows, r, localization, settings, rstudio

I am using R on Windows 7. Apparently R somehow found evidence that I speak languages besides English, and stubbornly insists on giving output in the console in my own language. For a variety of reasons, this is undesirable, and I want R to be English.

### What works

I am able to use `LANGUAGE=en` as a command line option for the R console desktop shortcut, but the language is still wrong in Rstudio, which launches the R executable directly and hence ignores the command line arguments in the shortcut.

### What doesn't work

I have tried creating an `.Renviron` file under `C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents`, which is the path returned for the working directory by `getwd()`, with `LANGUAGE=en` in it. R ignores this. My `R_ENVIRON` and `R_ENVIRON_USER` variables show up as `""` so `.Renviron` should be the correct filename.

I have also tried creating `.Renviron` under `R_HOME\etc` (`R_HOME` points to `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0`) and R also ignores it.

I was somewhat successful with adding `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")` in `R_HOME\etc` - this made all output from the R console English, except for the initial copyright information.

### The question

How can I make R default to English such that this is propagated to RStudio?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On a fresh install, adding `language = en` to the `Rconsole` file (which exists by default under `R_HOME\etc`) will make R's language English in the R console as well as RStudio. This can be overridden by code in the working directory and RStudio's individual projects.

Comment: As @fffchao says: "it should be the Rconsole file, instead of Rprofile.site"

Comment: Note: Under Win 8, I had to run Wordpad with elevated privileges (go to top right, search wordpad, run with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to be able to edit `Rconsole`.

Comment: Superbest's initial answer was flawed, and he/she changed after I posted my correct answer. He/she should give credit to me.

Comment: @fffchao I'm quite confused. When I posted this answer, it referenced `Rprofile.site`. I had discovered that at the time, this was a viable method of changing the language. I had tried it and it worked (at least at the time). It appears that Marco has decided to "correct" my answer (an edit against the rules since it changes the intent, in fact) in 2015 to say `Rconsole` (which at the time I had found to *not* work). Now you are accusing me of stealing your credit, when I had posted and accepted my answer the year prior to you posting yours.

Comment: @Superbest original suggestion to add `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")` to `Rprofile.site` worked for me in R 3.6.2 on Windows 7 Ultimate K. But, the easiest solution is to uninstall R and reinstall. Un-click the "translate error messages" during re-insulation. This way everything will be in English, including the initial copyright information, and you don't need to edit any files. This is true when running R or RStudio. The following discussion provides more information: [How to change language settings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r).

Answer (score 23):

First, go to the `etc` folder under R program files folder.  Then locate `Rconsole` file. Find the line `language =`, change it to `language = en`  if you want to run R in English.

**Note**:  right click on the Rconsole file icon, select Property and grant yourself the permission to modify the file.

Answer (score 14):

it should be the Rconsole file, instead of Rprofile.site.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is not in R or in RStudio, the problem is in your Windows language configuration.

If you are using Windows, you have to set it like this (e.g. Windows 7):

1. Control Panel
2. Region and language.

   2.1. Go to the Tab "Administrative"

   - "Language for non-Unicode programs", then set it in the "Change system locale" button.

   2.2. If you want, you can set it also the Tab "Format" in Format.

Cheers,
Darwin PC

Comment: This fixed my problem that I was having with a bunch of programs

Comment: This would likely break encoding many programs in said native language (for example, when I had Japanese locale, files opened in Notepad with Polish characters in them would display random Japanese glyphs instead of them, and Polish version of Winrar displays question marks instead of Polish characters).

Comment: I think the problem originate from window system does not support utf-8. In 2019, there exist a beta version in windows for supporting `non-Unicode programs` displaying. @Noctiphobia

Answer (score 12):

1. Go into R installation directory, i.e. `C:\Program Files\R\`
2. From there go into the subfolder `etc/`
3. Open with a text editor (i.e. Notepad) the file `Rconsole`
4. Look into the file for the line `language =`
5. Replace such line with `language = en`
6. Save and close the `Rconsole` file, then run Rgui again, and the
   interface will be in English

***R version 3.1.3***

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing my laptop's system preference->region as US. Then, re-install the R. The system language changed ultimately to english.

> sessionInfo()

locale: [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Problem with this is that you may want a different locale for other programs.