# How to change language settings in R

Tags: r

My error messages are displayed in French. How can I change my system language setting so the error messages will be displayed in English?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can set this using the `Sys.setenv()` function. My R session defaults to English, so I'll set it to French and then back again:

```
> Sys.setenv(LANG = "fr")
> 2 + x
Erreur : objet 'x' introuvable
> Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
> 2 + x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

A list of the abbreviations can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1).

`Sys.getenv()` gives you a list of all the environment variables that are set.

Comment: This changes the Lang temporarily(during the R session).  To change it once for all , you need to add the environment variable to your system, and relaunch RStudio so thistake effect.

Comment: This solution works well but when I reopen R it returns to my locale (which is Italian).

Comment: @SabDeM - yes, indeed. Heed the note of agstudy above and set the environment variable: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/EnvVar.html

Answer (score 48):

In the case of RStudio for Windows I succeeded in changing the language following the instructions found in [R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-want-R-in-English_0021), in particular I wrote:

```
language = EN
```

inside the file `Rconsole` (in my installation it is `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\etc\Rconsole`); this works also for the command `Rscript`.

For example you can locate the `Rconsole` file with this two commands from a command prompt:

`cd \`

`dir Rconsole /s`

The first one make the root as the current directory, the second one looks for the `Rconsole` file.

In the following screenshot you have that `Rconsole` file is in the folder `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\etc`.

You may have more than one location, in that case you may edit all the `Rconsole` files.

[image]

After that you can open the `Rconsole` file with your favorite editor and look for the line `language =` and then append `EN` at the end of that line.

In the following screenshot the interesting line is the number 70 and you have to append `EN` at the end of it.
[image]

Comment: Does not work for me. Changing the file and setting the language to EN has no effect on the language of error messages. I can see that it would be logical for this to work, but I assume that in the meantime Windows has several other language configuration directives (maybe the system's language, the system's keyboard layout) that interact in complex and intransparent ways.

Comment: @0range did you try `cd \ ` and `dir Rconsole /s` in order to look for multiple files?

Answer (score 26):

For mac users, I found this on the [R for Mac FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html)

> If you use a non-standard setup (e.g. different language than
>   formats), you can override the auto-detection performed by setting
>   `force.LANG' defaults setting, such as for example
>
> ```
>  defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
> ```
>
> when run in Terminal it will enforce US-english setting regardless of the system
>   setting. If you don't know what Terminal is you can use this R command
>   instead:
>
> ```
>  system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
> ```
>
> but do not forget to quit R and start R.app again afterwards. Please
>   note that you must always use `.UTF-8' version of the locale,
>   otherwise R.app will not work properly.

This helped me to change my console language from Chinese to English.

Comment: Confirmed as working for macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and R3.2.3 today

Answer (score 25):

This works from command line :

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

None of the other answers above worked for me

Comment: if one runs R directly from the command line, the answer above can be written inside the `.bash_profile` file (in Mac OS). Then, just type `source .bash_profile` to make the change effective in the window. _obs_: assuming `pwd` is `~`, i.e. home directory.

Answer (score 17):

If you use Ubuntu you will set

```
LANGUAGE=en
```

in `/etc/R/Renviron.site`.

Comment: This is true but not very helpful since you have to edit that file from the terminal. For noobs like me googling this here is how: type `sudo nano /etc/R/Renviron.site` into the terminal, followed by your password when the terminal asks you for it. Then you can edit that file right in the terminal. Add the line linellobocki mentions, then push `ctrl + x` to exit. Then type `y` to confirm that you want to save changes and hit enter to confirm the name and directory of the file.

Comment: How can I do this in anaconda environment? You must know when using a supercomputer it usual to install R and dependencies locally, and anaconda is good for that, but now I need to set the LANGUAGE to 'en' and IDK where it is this Renviron.site file

Comment: It works for me (terminal) but the file is '~/.Renviron.site`.

Answer (score 8):

You may also want to be aware of the difference between, for example, `Sys.setenv(LANG = "ru")` and `Sys.setlocale(locale = "ru_RU.utf8")`.

```
> Sys.setlocale(locale = "ru_RU.utf8")
[1] "LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8;LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.utf8;LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.utf8;LC_MESSAGES=en_IE.utf8;LC_PAPER=en_IE.utf8;LC_NAME=en_IE.utf8;LC_ADDRESS=en_IE.utf8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_IE.utf8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IE.utf8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IE.utf8"
```

If you are interested in changing the behaviour of functions that refer to one of these elements (e.g `strptime` to extract dates), you should use `Sys.setlocale()`.
See `?Sys.setlocale` for more details.
In order to see all available languages on a linux system, you can run

```
system("locale -a", intern = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 8):

To permanently make it works, in both R and Rstudio (with Win 10),
one way to do this is to run the script every time automatically in the background initially.

No more changing the system language that influence the windows.
No more R only but fail in Rstudio. No more run a script every time manually. No more admin right but fail. No more short-cut setting but fail.

Step 1.
Use your system search, to find the file named "Rprofile"

My response is

C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\library\base\R

C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\etc

Step 2.
Edit C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\library\base\R\Rprofile

The content:

- This is the system Rprofile file. It is always run on startup.
- Additional commands can be placed in site or user Rprofile files
- (see ?Rprofile)
  ... and so on.

Step 3. Add Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en") at the end of the scrip

```
local({
    Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
})
```

P.S. If you encounter the issue of authorization/saving,
move this file to desktop and replace the original file after editing.

Comment: I am confused. Other answers propose setting "LANG", others "LANGUAGE". Why?

Comment: Does not matter in fact. The only question is if this method(both "LANG"/"LANGUAGE") works for you. Have fun in the data science.

Comment: Thank you. This is also very handy whenn using renv

Answer (score 5):

type this first:
**system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")**
then you will get a index number(in my case is 127)

then type:
 **Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")**
then type the number and ENTER
**127**

Comment: this was only working for me during one R session

Answer (score 5):

For me worked:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "en_US.utf8")
```

Testing:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "en_US.utf8")
[1] "en_US.utf8"
> x[3]
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Also working to get english messages:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "C")
```

To reset to german messages I used

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "de_DE.utf8")
```

Here is the start of my `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: Note: This does not work on Windows (see help for `Sys.setlocale`: "Some systems (not Windows) will also support LC_MESSAGES...")

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be setting export Lang=C in your bash script.
I had a similar issue where the default language was german so it reverted back to english.

Comment: From R one can do `system("export Lang=C")`

Comment: This is a good solution. I'm running R using anaconda and your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change R's language in terminal to English forever, this works fine for me in macOS:

Open terminal.app, and say:

```
touch .bash_profile
```

Then say:

```
open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile
```

These two commands will help you open ".bash_profile" file in TextEdit.

Add this to ".bash_profile" file:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then save the file, reopen terminal and type `R`, you will find it's language has changed to english.

If you want language come back to it's original, just simply add a `#` before `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling R entirely (make sure to remove it from the Programs files as well), and install it, but *unselect* Message Translations during the installation process. When I installed R, and subsequently RCmdr, it finally came up in English.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I had to remove the `#` from the comment `#LANGUAGE=EN`.
All other options din not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your current regional format to a different regional format in region settings on time&language settings in Windows by clicking on your time/date in lower right corner > adjust time/date > Region > change regional format to UK or US

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with a windows 10 laptop in German, where I wanted i.e. lubridate to return dates in English:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using R Studio on a Mac and I couldn't find the Rconsole file. So I took a more brutal way and just deleted the unwanted language files from the R app.
You just have to go to your Rapp in your application Folder, right click, show package content then /contents/Resources/. There are the language files e.g. English.lproj or in my case de.lproj wich I deleted. After restarting R, error messages appear in English..
Maybe thats helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to change the basic language of microsoft on your computer!

press the windows button together with r, and tip the following code into the window that is opened

control.exe /name Microsoft.Language

load the language package you want to use and change the options. but take care, this will change also your keyboard layout!

Answer (score 0):

on windows, **when you have no admin right**, just create a new **program shortcut to Rgui.exe**. Then in the properties of that shortcut, go to the 'Shortcut' tab and modify the target to include the system language of your choice, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" LANGUAGE=en`

Answer (score 0):

I know a very simple solution to the problem of how to change the language of error messages and program descriptions in Rstudio, R, and R Commander.

The answer:

Go to C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\library\translations and delete the folder with the language you are trying to avoid, for example, "ru", "fr", and so on. If you are not sure or afraid of something ... -)), you can move the folder to another location, for example, to D:. That’s it.

Of course, you should do the above things in your current version of R. The version I use now is R-4.3.1.
This is the advice that Professor John Fox (the author of  R Commander) gave me several years ago. Thank you, Professor!

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to change language in RStudio:
1: Go to directory C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\library\base\R
Add this code at the end of the RProfile

```
   local({
        Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
    })
```

2: Go to directory C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\etc
add en to RConsole file.

### Language for messages

language = en  // add en

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you would have to edit the file `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Renviron` as administrator. Add the line `LANGUAGE=en` to the file. Tried with R version 4.3.2 under MacOS "Sonoma" 14.3.