# Irreproducible example in big.matrix documentation (apply)

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I'm new in the `big.matrix` and related packages, I try to reproduce the following example 
```

```
Loading required package: stats
> Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
> library(bigmemory)
Loading required package: bigmemory.sri

bigmemory >= 4.0 is a major revision since 3.1.2; please see package
biganalytics and http://www.bigmemory.org for more information.

> x <- big.matrix(5, 2, type="integer", init=0, dimnames=list(NULL, c("alpha", "beta")))
> x[,] <- round(rnorm(10))
Assignment will down cast from double to integer
Hint: To remove this warning type:  options(bigmemory.typecast.warning=FALSE)
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In SetAll.bm(x, value) : 
> x
An object of class "big.matrix"
Slot "address":
<pointer: 0x22a1620>

> x[,]
     alpha beta
[1,]    -2    0
[2,]    -1    0
[3,]     0   -1
[4,]     2    1
[5,]     0    0
> apply(x, 1, mean)
Error en as.vector(data) : 
  ningún método para coaccionar a esta clase S4 a un vector
```

from the documentation, but the last line gives me the following error:

```
Error en as.vector(data) : 
  ningún método para coaccionar a esta clase S4 a un vector
```

The last line says something like `"there is no method for transform this S4 class to a vector"`

Could you give me a pointer?

My R version is

```
R.version
               _                            
platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                       
os             linux-gnu                    
system         x86_64, linux-gnu            
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.1                         
year           2012                         
month          06                           
day            22                           
svn rev        59600                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
nickname       Roasted Marshmallows
```

Comment: I think it is better to set (temporary ) your environment language to English , e.g Sys.setenv(LANG = "en"), to get more help.

Comment: Thanks for yous suggestion, but the error still appears in spanish, see the edited question above...

Comment: hum..are you sure? see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r for more details

Comment: Thanks for the link, let me find what's wrong with my env...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to call `apply` in a bigmemory object. The latter don't have an implicit method to convert to a matrix(argument needed by apply)

```
apply(x, 1, mean)
Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Forcing the conversion to a matrix, correct the problem

```
apply(as.matrix(x), 1, mean)
[1] -1.5 -0.5  1.0 -0.5 -0.5
```

Edit after OP answer:

The package **biganalytics** extends the bigmemory package with various
analytics. Functions bigkmeans and binit may also be used with
native R objects. But be careful:

> apply for big.matrix objects. Note that the performance may be
>   degraded (compared to apply with regular R matrices) because of S4
>   overhead associated with extracting data from big.matrix objects. This
>   sort of limitation is unavoidable and would be the case (or even
>   worse) with other "custom" data structures. Of course, this would only
>   be partically significant if you are applying over lengthy rows or
>   columns.

For tapply-like functions, the **bigtabulate**
package may also be helpful.
The idea with this package is to do the job in 2 steps.

> We have found that bigsplit followed by lapply or sapply can be
>   particularly effective, when the subsets produced by the split are of
>   reasonable size.

Comment: You are right, but I think that transform the `big.matrix` to `matrix` defeats all the purpose of the `big.memory` package...

Comment: since you put me in the right direction... Do you want to change your answer to incorporate the `biganalytics`package (see my answer below) , so I can close this question as answered by you?

Comment: No. it is answered by you. It is encouraged in SO. you can check your answer and close the topic.

Comment: I agree that when in doubt it's nice to give credit to the lower-rep person.  On the other hand, this answer actually answers the original question. Since agstudy doesn't mind, I would suggest editing the original question slightly so that it doesn't just ask "what's wrong?", but rather "what's wrong ... and how do I achieve the goal of calculating row means?"

Comment: PS: I would also like to see a pointer/explanation of why you thought `apply` should work/whether it is **explicitly** suggested in the docs ... I don't see it? (There is supposedly an `apply` method, but I don't see an explicit example using it ...)

Comment: @BenBolker you're right. I think it is better to change the question, to something like "how to call t-appaly function to a bigmemory object?"

Answer (score 2):

Well, I discover the error thanks to the previous answer (#agstudy, I give you a +1)... The  `apply` method was from the `base`package, If I load the `biganalytics`packages, everything works as charm...

```
> library(biganalytics)
> apply(x, 1, mean)
[1]  0.0  1.5  0.5 -1.0  0.5
```

Thank you again!

Comment: good! maybe I want ask you how do you have the idea , just because it is a bixXXX package?

Comment: Hahahah, you are right!, please see my comment to your first answer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is slightly off-topic from the original question, not "why doesn't `apply(...)` work?", which @agstudy answered above, but "how do I get row means for a `bigmemory` object?" I googled `"r bigmemory rowmeans"` and ended up here: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/HPCwR/examples/bioinfo/bioinfo3.txt

Reproducing an interesting snippet:

```
# Get the row means, three different ways.

system.time({
  a <- rep(0, nrow(z))
  for (i in 1:nrow(z)) {
    a[i] <- mean(z[i,])
  }
}) # Will definitely work on both matrix and big.matrix
   # matrix timing: about 30 seconds
   # big.matrix timing: about 270 seconds
   #    The price for using bigmemory with lots of very small
   #    operations is the overhead of S3/S4 dispatch.

system.time({
  a <- apply(z, 1, mean)
}) # Works on a matrix only; interesting that it is slower.
   # matrix timing: 45 seconds 

system.time({
  myfunc <- function(i) return(mean(z[i,]))
  a <- sapply(1:nrow(z), myfunc)
}) # Will definitely work on both matrix and big.matrix
   # matrix timing:     About 40 seconds
   # big.matrix timing: About 306 seconds
```

The example goes on to show how to use parallel methods (`doMC` etc.) to compute row means.