# Namespace issue with raster package plot function?

Tags: r, namespaces, raster

I have experiencing a weird problem with the 'plot' function of the 'raster' package.

```
library(raster)
ras <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
```

EDIT

```
values(ras) <- runif(ncell(ras))
```

END EDIT

```
plot(ras)

Erreur dans as.double(y) : 
cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

For what I have read on the net, this error depends on the user, and probably depends on the loaded packages. In my case, the problem comes from the fact that r uses the standard 'plot' method from the 'graphics' package, when it should use the specific 'raster' method since 'ras' is a rasterLayer object. However, for a reason I do not understand, 'plot' is not imported in the 'raster' namespace, while all the other functions are.

```
> raster::plot
Erreur : 'plot' n'est pas un objet exporté depuis 'namespace:raster'
```

To be compared with :

```
raster::persp
standardGeneric for "persp" defined from package "graphics"
function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("persp")
<environment: 0x0cd9eb80>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("persp")  for currently available ones.
```

Since I do not completely understand how namespaces behave, I am looking for your help ! Is this kind of situation familiar for you, and do you have a way to solve it ? In the meantime, do you know a function to display the content of a namespace (so I could check the content of the raster namespace step by step) ?

PS: I am using R 2.15.2 with RStudio, many packages loaded but all are up to date.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252          LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.0-41 sp_1.0-5     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] grid_2.15.0      hexbin_1.26.0    intervals_0.13.3 lattice_0.20-6   rgdal_0.8-4      spacetime_1.0-3  spam_0.29-2      tools_2.15.0    
 [9] xts_0.9-2        zoo_1.7-9
```

Thanks you,

François

Comment: I get a different error  after the first three lines `Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  : 
  no values associated with this RasterLayer`. Use the example from the help and see if you can replicate your error.

Comment: I get the same error as mnel...PS : you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r) to have error message in English..

Comment: Yes, I forgot to fill the raster with numbers, sorry. Now it should work (or fail the same way it does for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this you get all the list of object of package raster

```
basevals <- ls(pos="package:raster")
```

for example

```
   which(basevals == 'persp')  ## function persp shows up because it is the exported generic.
   141
   which(basevals == 'plot')   ## no function plot
   integer(0)
```

No when I do this , it works for me:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
plot(r, main='Raster with 100 cells')
```

So There is certainly a plot method here. It is not in the previous list "basevals"  beacuse it is  an S4 method.

To get the plot method of raster package , try this :

```
 getMethod('plot',signature=signature(x='Raster', y='ANY'))
```

or more efficiently using

```
findMethods("plot", "package:raster").
```

Comment: +1. I'd forgotten this was an S4 issue. There is certainly a `plot` method there, just not an S3 one hence your first part of the answer shows no plot method whilst `persp` shows up because it is the exported generic. The last bit can be done a bit more efficiently using `findMethods("plot", "package:raster")`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the fact that I had not found the raster plot method does not mean it does not exist. But 'getMethod' does not get it either. getMethod('plot',signature=signature(x='Raster', y='ANY'))
Error in getMethod("plot", signature = signature(x = "Raster", y = "ANY")) : 
  No method found for function "plot" and signature Raster

Comment: @fstevens can you try this in you R session please...and if not give me your sessionInfo()?

Comment: @fstevens oops ..maybe it is better to do it new R session...  where you have fewer packages..

Comment: @agstudy I have done it with only basic packages + raster. The simple example still fails.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23092/discussion-between-agstudy-and-fstevens)

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens when you have a stale session (typically caused by loading an old session at startup), that goes away if you start a fresh R session (without loading previously saved sessions).

Comment: I've been having the same problem. I'm not sure how you load a new session without it automatically loading previous settings so I deleted all my .R* files from the working dir and it seems to be functioning again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and re-installing the raster package fixed it.

```
install.packages("raster")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what resolved this S4 class namespace issue was to add the `raster` package as a Dependency. Hence, using the `attach()` function should also work, as that is what dependencies do. I know that is not an ideal solution, but hey, it's a statistics language ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've been running in the same error, also using RStudio.

My issues was that I loaded the `raster` package via `library(raster)` in the `.Rprofile` file of my project. But code in Rprofile gets loaded before anything else, so the `graphics` package (containing the plot generic) is loaded after raster, causing the problems.

Solution: Put `library(graphics)` before `library(raster)` in Rprofile, and it worked for me.