# How to change the locale of R?

Tags: r, locale

I’m using R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) on Ubuntu 12.10. The System is in German and so is R. This comes unhandy when searching for error messages.

Executing R in xterm this way  `$ LANG="C" R` partially solves the issue. Then R displays everything in English. But when loading RStudio this way, the R interpreter is still in German. So I’m looking for a way to change the locale of R in R itself.

I found this: [How to change language settings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r), but `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")` does’t work for me:

```
2+x
# Fehler: Objekt 'x' nicht gefunden
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
2+x
# Fehler: Objekt 'x' nicht gefunden
```

I also tried `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")` with no success.

Output of `Sys.getlocale()`

```
Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8;
# LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8;
# LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8;
# LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

(linebrakes added for convenience)

Comment: Have you tried `LANG` between quotes and/or unshortened (i.e., `LANGUAGE`)? Anyway, I'm not sure this is the way to approach the issue; my system shows errors in English even though `Sys.getlocale` shows `Portuguese_Brazil.1252` all around.

Answer (score 62):

Just had the same problem and found the solution that worked for me on Windows/Linux:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

Comment: This does not change language of the error messages in my cases (Ubuntu + OSX), try e. g. `log("a")` and check the language of the error message

Comment: "Warning message: In `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")`: OS reports request to set locale to "English" cannot be honored"

Comment: The reason is that locales are platform-specific. `"English"` works on Windows, but not on OpenSUSE Leap 15.2, for example.

Answer (score 17):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", 'en_GB.UTF-8')
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")
```

This 2 worked for me. No more polish error messages in eclipse R. Though I think only the 2nd had effect. Thanks

edit: although I have to execute those every time i restart R environment.

Comment: Is there a workaround concerning the restart? I face the same problem...

Comment: add that lines to .Rprofile file that gets automatically executed each time you run R session

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do this temporarily, you can try starting R from the command line preceded by setting the language in-line:

```
# start R with LANGUAGE set to Mandarin
LANGUAGE=zh_CN.UTF-8 R --no-save
# do R stuff
q()
# any LANGUAGE set in your env will be unaffected afterwards
env | grep LANGUAGE
```

Comment: I think its important to start R with the locale pre-set this way, particularly if you need to mess with LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL.  In my case, I was setting `LC_ALL` to `ja_JP.SJIS` and I had to also change my terminal's encoding.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

In **Ubuntu** (14.04) this is the solution that worked for me:

Edit the .Renviron file in your home directory and add this line:

```
LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
# for R with British accent use en_GB.utf8
```

Then restart R.

Answer (score 7):

In my cases (OSX High Sierra + Ubuntu 14.04) I could switch the language of R output to English only by using this command (with immediate effect without  restarting the R session):

```
Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")
```

To permanently change the language either add the above line to your `Rprofile.site` file (see `?Startup`) or create/edit the file `.Renviron` in your home folder (`~/`) and enter a line with `LANGUAGE=en` or similar (like `LANGUAGE="fr_FR.utf8"` for French with UTF-8 encoding which is used by default in Linux).

Answer (score 7):

Surprisingly among so many answers I don't see an answer that I would prefer myself.

```sh
echo 'LC_ALL=C' >> ~/.Renviron
```

This will append (or create if doesn't exist) a environment configuration line to `.Renviron` file which is meant to be used exactly for this purpose.

After that any `R` process started should already have locale specified in `.Renviron` file.

Comment: This also works well with the `/etc/R/Renviron` file (using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), +1.

Comment: Be careful `LC_ALL=C` in `/etc/R/Renviron` crashes Shiny Server.  `LANGUAGE=en` R Yoda answer works in `/etc/R/Renviron`.

Comment: `sudo su - -c "echo 'LANGUAGE=en' >> /etc/R/Renviron"`

Answer (score 4):

Try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", 'en_GB.UTF-8')
```

Taken from: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Localization-of-messages  which should be consulted for further details.

Comment: For completeness can you also try values of "EN" and "en_GB"? After taht I would think it needful to establish whether the EN file ahs been lost or damaged.

Comment: I tried several other variations of "EN", but R stays in German. I Don’t think the EN file is lost or damaged, because starting R with `"LANG="C"` works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing my Macbook's system preference->region as US. Then, re-install the R. Then, the system language changed ultimately.

> sessionInfo()

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

You just need to

1. Open Terminal
2. Write or paste in: **defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG
   en_US.UTF-8**
3. Close Terminal and restart R

It worked for me in OS X

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an issue of your Ubuntu, not R. If the OS does not have correct locale setting of "en", the R cannot use it. Check out the OS locales. Or using locale 'C' instead of 'en' may work still.

```
Sys.setenv(LANG='C')
```

Comment: still doesn’t work :-(

I added the locales recognized by R to the original question.