# order() arranges letters v, w incorrectly in R

Tags: r, sorting

I'm trying to sort a vector containing all the different states of America. However, when using the `order` function, R fails to order those states that start with V or W in the correct order, instead sorting them by the following letter. Like this:

```
first.states <- c("AL", "AR", "CA", "CO", "AZ", "AK", "CT")
first.states[order(first.states)]

[1] "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" "CA" "CO" "CT" #Very good!

last.states <- c("WA", "VA", "WY", "WI", "VT", "WV", "VI")
last.states[order(last.states)]

[1] "VA" "WA" "VI" "WI" "VT" "WV" "WY" #Sad face
```

Does anybody have a clue about what's happening? `arrange` from `dplyr` gives me the correct solution, but I cannot use it for this problem.

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252"
```

Comment: Looks like a locale issue, for example in Finnish V and W are equal when ordering. But can't say much more since I don't have information about how R handles locales.

Comment: Your code does not produce your output to me because of `locale` settings. What `Sys.getlocale()` returns?

Comment: This is why the posting guide for R-Help suggests you post `sessionInfo()` with every question....

Comment: Could've figured. Yeah, I'm in Sweden.
`> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252"` How can I get around this?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r-in-rstudio)

Comment: #MichaelChirico Thanks, I noticed that topic, but I refrained because the help file of Sys.setlocale says "Attempts to change the character set (by Sys.setlocale("LC_TYPE", ), if that implies a different character set) during a session may not work and are likely to lead to some confusion."