# Extract label names from datetime

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, label, axis

I'm making a ggplot.

The data is looking like this:

```
df$Measure         df$Date        df$House
0.006              2015-01-13        A  
0.008              2015-01-13        A
0.002              2015-02-13        C
0.010              2015-03-13        D
0.010              2015-03-13        B
```

I plot the data with:

```
ggplot (df) +geom_line(aes(y = df$Measure, x = df$Date)) +
  facet_wrap(~House) + labs (tittle = "Energy total per House") +
  ylab ("Energy value") + xlab ("Months")
```

The data plot is good, but I got a problem. The x-axis is plotted automatic, but with dutch translations.

So I got on the X- axis: feb, mrt, apr, mei, jun, jul, aug, sep

But I want to have this in English: feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep 
How is this possible? I tried to change them, but I didn't worked, because the months are automatic extracted.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r-in-rstudio

Comment: Really thanks. This worked: 

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US")