# Shiny/DT: column & top filter for datetime column show wrong values

Tags: r, datetime, shiny, dt

I am having bit of trouble to figure out why my **column and filter** for datetime column shows the wrong date and time.

My data looks like this (`dput` **is in shiny code below**):

```
                 DATUM NUMMER
1  2017-03-29 00:00:02     19
2  2017-03-29 00:00:36     20
3  2017-03-29 00:00:40     21
4  2017-03-29 00:00:44     22
5  2017-03-29 00:00:47     23
6  2017-03-29 00:00:51     24
7  2017-03-29 00:00:55     25
8  2017-03-29 00:00:59     26
9  2017-03-29 00:01:03     27
10 2017-03-29 00:01:07     28
```

As we can see, it is nothing special. After displaying this data in shiny using `DT` package, the data looks like this:

[image]

it is displayed with 2h difference, without any reason...

My **first approach** was to check my `Sys.time()`

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2017-03-30 09:09:40 CEST"
```

and it is correct, **second approach** was to dig into `DT` documentation, and there i have found the function: `formatDate(1, method = 'toLocaleString')`. I have used it, the display of the datetime field appeared to be good (see pic below), however the top filter still is showing the wrong datetime values...

[image]

**Here is the reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- structure(list(DATUM = structure(c(1490738402, 1490738436, 1490738440, 
                                           1490738444, 1490738447, 1490738451, 1490738455, 1490738459, 1490738463, 
                                           1490738467), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CEST"), NUMMER = c(19, 
                                                                                                                20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)), .Names = c("DATUM", "NUMMER"
                                                                                                                ), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

ui= fluidPage(

      dataTableOutput("tab")
    )

server= function(input, output,session) {

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data,rownames=TRUE, filter="top", class = 'cell-border stripe') %>%
      formatDate(1, method = 'toLocaleString')})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As we can see in the data the `min` datetime value is `2017-03-29 00:00:02`, however the top filter of `datatable` shows `2017-03-28T22:00:02`, whereas the `max` datetime value in data is: `2017-03-29 00:01:07`, the top filter shows: `2017-03-28T22:01:07`.

I would appreciate any help and explanation, why `DT` package transforms my data and displays it with 2h difference, and why after implying the function `formatDate()`, the filter still shows wrong values.

Thanks for help

Comment: Try setting locale http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r-in-rstudio

Comment: I have tried it, nothing has changed in displaying of datetime column

Comment: @HubertL i do not quite understand what do You mean by that

Comment: try with `tzone = "CET"`

Comment: I think the sole problem here is that `as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())` yields a two hour difference (2 a.m. instead of 12 a.m.), using `as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), tz = "CET")` did not work for me as well :-/

Comment: @shosaco thats actually strange, i have tried as well `as.POSIXct(Sys.time())` and got the correct value of datetime ...`> as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
[1] "2017-04-03 07:25:34 CEST"`

Comment: @HubertL i ahve already tried this approach, changing timezone, however it did not work in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for the noUISlider is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/ad11ba80cb17db9c34913a7d060638c990ed6d1e/inst/htmlwidgets/datatables.js). It looks like all the dates are treated as UTC when to get the min and max for the slider.

You can maybe transform the dates and times to the same dates and time in the UTC timezone to have consistency between the slider and your dates:

```
data$DATUM <- as.POSIXct(as.character(data$DATUM), tz="UTC")

ui=fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput("tab")
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data,rownames=TRUE, filter="top", class = 'cell-border stripe') %>%
      formatDate(1, method = 'toISOString')})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the slider is moved, there is a warning in the R console stating that time zones are inconsistent but the filtering works.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Finally it is working, it was a huge headache this one