# Changing time and dateformat to show correct format on shiny dashboard

Tags: r, datetime, shiny, datetime-format, shinydashboard

I've build this dashboard with multiple date and time columns however in the dashboard the "T" and "Z" popup in the display [image: LIKETHIS] Any ideas on how to remove this? I tried `as.character`, `as.factor`, `anytime` but I'm not able to make it happen.

Any other ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Suppose you converted the column to `character` i.e. `df1$time <- as.character(df1$time)` Can u show the output of the first five elements of that

Comment: @akrun, as.character was the first thing I tried but the "T" and "z" just don't go away!

Comment: @akrun, the output is the same as above there is no change!

Comment: @kishore have you tried the solution provided below? If it works, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 5):

[This happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517896/current-time-in-iso-8601-format) when you go from R to Javascript.  [You need to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110892/shiny-dt-column-top-filter-for-datetime-column-show-wrong-values):

```
 output$yourDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
     DT::datatable(df) %>% formatDate(3, "toLocaleString")
 })
```

Where the 3 represents the position of the date (as.POSIXct(), not factor, for example) column (e.g., third column) you are formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it in base R or with lubridate :

```
tz <- Sys.timezone()

date1 <- "2015-03-23T13:23:20Z"

# With {base}
strptime(date1, tz = tz, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
[1] "2015-03-23 13:23:20 CET"


#With lubridate
lubridate::ymd_hms(date1, tz = tz)
[1] "2015-03-23 14:23:20 CET"
```

You can of course specify a different timezone for `tz`.

Best,

Colin

Comment: I tried that too. but the output is like NA NA NA for all rows in the column.