# Error in gsub is too long with Arabic language in R

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, analysis, data-cleaning

I am doing text mining in R with Arabic language 
And use `gsub` function but I got an error as shown here

```
Error in gsub("^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})", "", x, perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '^\x{0627}\x{0644}(?=\p{L})'
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})", "", x, perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
        'character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large'
        at '}\x{0644}(?=\p{L})'
```

here is my code

```
x<-("الوطن")
# Remove leading alef lam with optional leading waw
m <- gsub('^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})', '', x, perl = TRUE)
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: This runs fine! I got `[1] "وطن"` as output. I had to replace your `”` to `"` before running

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the problem , 
the problem is : when I import data in Arabic language as csv then apply `gsub` I get the error

```
    Error in gsub("^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})", "", x, perl = TRUE) : 
   invalid regular expression '^\x{0627}\x{0644}(?=\p{L})'
   In addition: Warning message:
   In gsub("^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})", "", x, perl = TRUE) :
   PCRE pattern compilation error
        'character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large'
        at '}\x{0644}(?=\p{L})'
```

I figure out that I need to save the data with `encode= UTF-8` 
then read it also with `encode= UTF-8` Then change the Local .
like this code :

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","arabic")
[1] "Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256"
>  write.csv(x, file = "x.csv" , fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

y<-read.csv("C:/Users/Documents/x.csv",encoding ="UTF-8")
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","arabic")
[1] "Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256"
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me the only problem is your quotation marks:

```
> x <- "الوطن"
> gsub('^\\x{0627}\\x{0644}(?=\\p{L})', '', x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "وطن"
```

also, check for your OS locale as I've experienced some similar issues when trying to process Hebrew text while my Windows locale was set to US.

Comment: please run `Sys.getlocale()` and report back the output

Comment: `> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
`

Comment: So as I've previously said, the problem begins with your OS, you need to change locale so Arabic will be supported (windows 10: Settings>Time & Language>Region & language, select your country), then try again

Comment: Thank you to help me,  but still the error when I change the locale to Arabic  . 

any another way to solve this problem ?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r

Comment: `gsub` its working when I use the variable but when I import data as csv and apply `gsub` give me same error why  ?

Comment: try using the `enc2utf8` function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Spätzle to help me