# R how get a date from variable in character

Tags: r, date, datatable, data-cleaning

I have data that has dates in a character format, as "JAN2005","FEB2005","MAR2005", such as :

```
Test <- data.table(c("JAN2005","FEB2005","MAR2005","APR2005"),c(436.6,543.1,417.3,687.4))
```

Is there a simple way to get the date in an actual date format ?

Comment: Try `Test[, V1 := as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(V1))]`

Comment: I get no error message, but it does not work : the output is filled with <NA>

Comment: Not sure about your error.  Based on the example showed, it get `Test$V1
[1] "2005-01-01" "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01" "2005-04-01"`

Comment: Or with `base R` `Test[, V1 := as.Date(paste0(V1, '01'), "%b%Y%d")]#
> Test$V1
[1] "2005-01-01" "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01" "2005-04-01"`

Comment: Hmm, I get also NAs... Maybe a package issue

Comment: I am using only your example on `R 3.6.2`

Comment: I am in R 3.6.1 and a bit puzzled. I have a few additional packages

Comment: May be it is related to the locale i.e. if your locale settings are different, then it may not match the month. According to `?strptime` `%b -Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform. (Also matches full name on input: in some locales there are no abbreviations of names.)`

Comment: My locale info is `locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Maybe you are on something, I am French and my locale seems to be in French : `"LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"`

Comment: You can change it to US or English.  that is the isssue

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r) for setting the locale

Comment: It does work indeed. I changed the locale using `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
`. Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
Test[, V1 := as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(V1))]
```

Or convert to a proper 'Date' by `paste`ing the day as well and then use `as.Date`

```
Test[, V1 := as.Date(paste0(V1, '01'), "%b%Y%d")]
```

If the locale is different from English, change it to match the 'month' as it is in English

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

Comment: I am going to accept your answer, but it might be useful to add a note about the locale ? Or maybe I should ask another question about that ?