# Create a sequence of times in R?

Tags: r, chron

I want to create a sequence of times 00:00 - 12:00 and 12:00 to 00:00 with 10 minutes step.
How can I do this in R?

I have tried with:

```
library(chron)
t <- merge(0:23, seq(0, 50, by = 10))
chron(time = paste(x$x, ':', x$y), format = c(times = "h:m"))
```

But I have 2 problems:

1. I get an error running `chron(time = paste(x$x, ':', x$y), format = c(times = "h:m"))`:

> Error in convert.times(times., fmt) : format h:m may be incorrect

2. How can I turn it to standard time with AM/PM? Should I merge it twice:

`t <- merge(0:12, seq(0, 50, by = 10))`

`t_am <- merge(t, "AM")`

`t_pm <- merge(t, "PM")`

Or maybe another way using POSIXt?

Comment: Can you show first few values of expected output?

Comment: 00:00AM, 00:10AM, .... 11:50AM, 12:00PM, 12:10PM, 12:50PM, 01:00PM .... 11:50PM, 00:00AM ... @RonakShah

Comment: `chron` needs a number of seconds as well. `tms <- paste0(sprintf("%02d", t$x), ':', sprintf("%02d", t$y), ":00")` followed by `chron(times = tms, format = c(times = "h:m:s"))` solves your first question.

Comment: @Bas why it gives me to change a format if it doesn't support removing the seconds?
Weird...

Comment: But where is the AM/PM strings? @ronak-shah

Comment: @SteveS, it allows the order of `h`, `m`, and `s` to be changed, but not which of those you include. I have never used `chron` before and I don't know why they made that decision, though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` :

```
format(seq(as.POSIXct('00:00', format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), 
           as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 1), by = '10 mins'), "%I:%M%p")

#[1] "12:00AM" "12:10AM" "12:20AM" "12:30AM" "12:40AM" "12:50AM" "01:00AM ...
#[141] "11:20PM" "11:30PM" "11:40PM" "11:50PM" "12:00AM"
```

Make sure you have the correct locale or set it via :

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")!
```

Comment: But where is the AM/PM strings? @ronak-shah

Comment: What do you mean? I see `AM`/`PM` strings in the output.

Comment: Here is what I get:

[1] "12:00" "12:10" "12:20" "12:30" "12:40" "12:50" "01:00" "01:10" "01:20" "01:30" "01:40" "01:50" "02:00" "02:10"

Comment: platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

Comment: do you have any idea why do I get without AM/PM?
And please correct me if I am wrong - you added ```Sys.Date() + 1``` because it's the next day? @ronak-shah

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you. Yes, we create sequence of 10 minute intervals from today to tomorrow and using `format` we print those datetime in `"%I:%M%p"` format. `%I` is what prints `AM`/`PM`. You can check that in `?strptime`

Comment: Ok, so how can I solve it and force it to print AM PM? @ronak-shah

Comment: Maybe you have different version of R? I am running your code and get different results...weird

Comment: What is your locale? Is it English? If not, then try switching to English and check.

Comment: My locale is:
"LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_IL.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_IL.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_IL.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IL.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Should I change it? @ronak-shah?

Comment: Yes, please change it according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r . Also, can you try to use `"%r"` instead of `"%I:%M%p"` and see if it works?

Comment: Here is what I get:
"04:30:00 " "04:40:00 " "04:50:00 " "05:00:00 " "05:10:00 " "05:20:00 " "05:30:00 " "05:40:00 " "05:50:00 " @ronak-shah with %r.

I will try changing the locale maybe this is the solution

Comment: For me both `"%r"` and `"%I:%M%p"` work flawlessly. They give output as `"12:00:00 AM" "12:10:00 AM"` and `"12:00AM" "12:10AM"`  respectively.

Comment: Changed the locale to English without luck:
 "12:00" "12:10" "12:20" "12:30" "12:40" "12:50" "01:00" "01:10" "01:20" "01:30" "01:40" "01:50" "02:00" "02:10"

```Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")``` @ronak-shah