# I´m having problems with Dates on R

Tags: r, lubridate

I had been trying to parse the code below with not good results. The function doesn´t recognize am/pm.

```
 library (tidyverse) 
 library (lubridate)
 c = c("28 de julio de 2020 6:02 PM Hora de Montevideo")
 dmy_hm (c)
```

#with this unsatisfactory result

[1] "2020-07-28 06:02:00 UTC"

The time must be 18:02:00.
Clearly I'm doing something wrong with LOCALE.
Could someone helpme?

Thanks

Comment: What locale are you currently using? i.e. what are `system("locale -a")` and  `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`?

Comment: Thank you Calumn. I'm using ** > Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
x = c("28 de julio de 2020 6:02 PM Hora de Montevideo")

#Set locale to spanish
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "es_ES")
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%d de %B de %Y %I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2020-07-28 18:02:00 UTC"

lubridate::dmy_hm(x)
#[1] "2020-07-28 18:02:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you  Ronak, but it doesn't work in my system. I dón't know why. When I ask to change Locale setting using> **Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "es_ES")**, the System retieves me with Warning message:
**In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "es_ES") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "es_ES" cannot be honored** Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Can you try `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish")`. See various options here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r

Comment: @mpo Hi, were you able to resolve this? Did you get the answer that you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Ronak,  I can't. What I'm doing is editing the data, on excel. Probably the problem is that my system. I tried using  "Sys.setlocale ("LC_ALL", "Spanish")" But it doesn`t work.

Comment: Hí, I could finally. Probably the problem was that I´m using Windows. My code ` Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
[1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"
> x= c("27 de julio de 2020 3:43 PM Hora de Montevideo")
> as.POSIXct(x, format = '%d de %B de %Y %I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC')
[1] "2020-07-27 15:43:00 UTC" `                  Thank you very much.