# Set locale on shinyapps.io via GHActions

Tags: r, shiny, github-actions, shinyapps

I have [this dashboard](https://albersonmiranda.shinyapps.io/econdashboard/) and it's locale is currently set to english (see months names). I've tried, as you can see [here](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/econdashboard/runs/2241375136?check_suite_focus=true), to set mac-os and R locale to `pt_BR` via:

```
      - name: change macos locale
        run: |
          export LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8  
          export LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8

      - name: change R locale
        run: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "pt_BR.UTF-8")
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

But still can't change it.

Comment: There's this line in ShinyApps.io log: `2021-03-31T23:06:14.112722+00:00 shinyapps[3094159]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Have you tried changing directly from the R code like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r

Comment: @TomasCapretto yeah, that's what second command does. Still doesn't works. (Added LANGUAGE variable, no good either).

Answer (score 2):

I've had success changing the locale in a shinyapps.io dashboard as follows:

1. Before you call rsconnect::deployApp, include in your R script

   options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE,
   rsconnect.locale = "pt_BR.UTF-8")
2. In your app.R file (or whatever file will actually be running on shinyapps.io), include the line

   Sys.setlocale(locale = "pt_BR.UTF-8")

As best I understand it, the first line tells shinyapps that it needs to have that language available, and the second tells R running on shinyapps to use that language.