# Use multiple locales in R ShinyApp deployed to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, setlocale, rsconnect

I've built an app where users have the option to generate reports in English, Spanish, and Portuguese. The reports have a time stamp at the top that relies on `Sys.setlocale` and `format` to translate and display the date properly depending on the selected language. (E.g. "02 março, 2023" for Portuguese.) Works locally, but fails on shinyapps.io with the following warnings in the log:

> OS reports request to set locale to "pt_BR.UTF-8" cannot be honored

> OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored

Stripped down app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tools) # cap functions

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId="langSel",
    label="Select Lanugage",
    choices=c("English"="en_US",
              "Spanish"="es_MX",
              "Portuguese"="pt_BR"),
    selected="en_US"
  ),
  textOutput("repDateOut")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  timeStamp <- "2023-03-02"
  
  # set locale depending on language selection to translate month
  observeEvent(input$langSel,{
    Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", paste0(input$langSel,".UTF-8"))
  })
  
  repDate <- reactive({
    dateOrder <- if (input$langSel=="en_US"){
      '%B %d, %Y' # month before day for English
    } else {
      '%d %B, %Y' # day before month for everything else
    }
    fmDate <- format(as.Date(timeStamp), dateOrder) %>%
      {if (input$langSel=="en_US") toTitleCase(.) else .} # cap month for English only
    fmDate
  })
  
  # print timestamp
  output$repDateOut <- renderText({repDate()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896516/set-locale-on-shinyapps-io-via-ghactions) about making non-local locales available in rsconnect before deploying, I've tried running a few things in the console to deploy the app:

Attempt 1:

```
options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE, rsconnect.locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE, rsconnect.locale = "pt_BR.UTF-8")
options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE, rsconnect.locale = "es_MX.UTF-8")
rsconnect::deployApp()
```

Attempt 2:

```
options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE, rsconnect.locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
options(rsconnect.locale = "pt_BR.UTF-8")
options(rsconnect.locale = "es_MX.UTF-8")
rsconnect::deployApp()
```

Attempt 3:

```
options(rsconnect.locale.cache = FALSE, rsconnect.locale = "en_US.UTF-8", rsconnect.locale = "pt_BR.UTF-8", 
rsconnect.locale = "es_MX.UTF-8")
rsconnect::deployApp()
```

In each case, only the Spanish locale (last one specified) works. (`rsconnect.locale=c("en_US.UTF-8","pt_BR.UTF-8","es_MX.UTF-8")` errors out at deployment.) Is there a way to make all three available in shinyapps.io?

Comment: While you might get something here on SO, you may be more likely to get a focused response on Posit forums and/or from their support team. (I can't help, sorry, though I know this is a good problem to solve.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) provided an answer on [rsconnect GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/1034) which worked like a charm:

> While we might want to somehow fix this on shinyapps, there is a fix that's available now (and is also more reliable than relying system locales): use a date-time package that has different locales built in. For example, here's an example using the clock package:

```
library(clock)

date <- as.Date("2023-01-02")

date_format(date, format = "%d %B %Y", locale = clock_locale("en"))
#> [1] "02 January 2023"
date_format(date, format = "%d %B %Y", locale = clock_locale("es"))
#> [1] "02 enero 2023"
date_format(date, format = "%d %B %Y", locale = clock_locale("pt"))
#> [1] "02 janeiro 2023"
```

Not only does it translate the months, but UTF-8 is also built-in so special characters are handled automatically, and month capitalization is also handled according to language.