# Change german month abbreviation in full name of the month in R

Tags: r

I would like to change german month abbreviations like "Jan", "Feb", "Mär, "Apr", "Mai", and so on, to the full name of the months. Like "Januar", "Februar", "März", ...

I guess there is no such function available. For English abbreviations, there is the function `month.abb`. Do you have an idea how I could do this not manually?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the function [`match`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) solves.

Using the built-in English names, you’d write

```
example_data = c('Jan', 'Dec', 'Mar')
month.name[match(example_data, month.abb)]
```

The same works for other languages, you’ll just have to define your own vectors for the month names and abbreviations.

Comment: is there a way to get the month names of the current locale?

Answer (score 6):

You can get full month name in the current locale with:

```
format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B")
#months(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1)) #Alternative
```

and abbreviated month name in the current locale with:

```
format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b")
#months(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), TRUE) #Alternative
```

To change the locale have a look at [How to change the locale of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16347731/10488504) in case `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")` is not working.

And to make the conversion local short to local long:

```
loc2loc <- setNames(format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%B"), format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b"))
loc2loc["Jan"]
```

and local short to English long:

```
loc2eng <- setNames(month.name, format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b"))
loc2eng["Jan"]
```

Or without using locales - hard coded:

```
de2de <- setNames(c("Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli"
  , "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"), c("Jan", "Feb"
  , "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"))
de2de[c("Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai")]
#      Jan       Feb      Mär       Apr       Mai 
# "Januar" "Februar"   "März"   "April"     "Mai"
```

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","de_DE.UTF-8")

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to do this, I wrote a function call.  Useful for vector operations and for coping with different possible inputs:

```
month.de <- function(mnth = "Jan") {
  dplyr::case_when(
            mnth == "Jan" ~ "Januar",
            mnth == "Feb" ~ "Febuar",
            mnth %in% c("Mar", "Mär") ~ "März",
            mnth == "Apr" ~ "April",
            mnth == "Mai" ~ "Mai",
            mnth == "Jun" ~ "Juni",
            mnth == "Jul" ~ "Juli",
            mnth == "Aug" ~ "August",
            mnth == "Sep" ~ "September",
            mnth == "Okt" ~ "Oktober",
            mnth == "Nov" ~ "November",
            mnth == "Dez" ~ "Dezember",
            mnth == TRUE ~ "Unknown")
}
```

Then `month.de("Mär")` gives "März".

Comment: this is a useful alternative, although `match()` as suggested by @KonradRudolph is much more compact ...