# How to convert a character into a date class?

Tags: r, date

Consider the following data

```
my_date <- "October 15, 2018"
```

I want to convert it into a date.

Thus, I tried to use the `as.Date` function like below

```
as.Date(my_date, format = "%B %d, %Y")
```

But, this returns just a `NA` and I cannot understand what is the problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You probably have a non-English locale hence R is not able to identify months in English. You may try to change the locale https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case you may or may not want to alter your locales. If the latter applies, `lubridate` parsers allow you to set `locale` just for the function, without changing your environment:

```r
lubridate::mdy("October 15, 2018", locale = "C")
#> [1] "2018-10-15"
```

Or if it's part of data import, perhaps consider `readr`, its default locale handling is quite convenient on non-US systems:

```r
library(readr)

# system lcoale:
Sys.getlocale()
#> [1] "LC_COLLATE=Estonian_Estonia.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Estonian_Estonia.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Estonian_Estonia.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Estonian_Estonia.utf8"

# E.g. for "%B %d, %Y" to work we would need "juuli" instead of "July":
format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")
#> [1] "juuli 24, 2023"

# readr::default_locale(), will be used by readr::parse_date() :
default_locale()
#> <locale>
#> Numbers:  123,456.78
#> Formats:  %AD / %AT
#> Timezone: UTC
#> Encoding: UTF-8
#> <date_names>
#> Days:   Sunday (Sun), Monday (Mon), Tuesday (Tue), Wednesday (Wed), Thursday
#>         (Thu), Friday (Fri), Saturday (Sat)
#> Months: January (Jan), February (Feb), March (Mar), April (Apr), May (May),
#>         June (Jun), July (Jul), August (Aug), September (Sep), October
#>         (Oct), November (Nov), December (Dec)
#> AM/PM:  AM/PM

# import CSV that uses foreign date format for that specific system locale, 
# without changing any locale settings:

dummy_csv <- '"October 15, 2018"';
read_csv(I(dummy_csv), col_names = FALSE, col_types = cols(col_date(format = "%B %d, %Y")))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   X1        
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2018-10-15
```