# Use rep in R over multiple lines

Tags: r

I have the following in a CSV file and I want to have them the same format, below, in R

```
01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00
15       80       67
30       44       2
```

I've been able to put them in a single variable

```
textus="01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 

15 80 67 

30 44 2"
```

Then

```
data <- unname(as.matrix(read.table(text = textus)))
```

After, I'm trying to put them together with the following command line:

```
data1 <- rep(data[1,],data[2,],data[3,])
```

But it keeps giving me the following error lines:

```
Message d'avis :
In rep(dat[1, ], dat[2, ], dat[3, ]) :
seul le premier élément de l'argument 'length.out' est utilisé
```

The error is in french, to make things worse.

I've tried the following and it works even if it is only doing half of what I wish R to do:

```
data1<-rep(dat[1,],dat[2,]) 

# results
01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00
15       80       67

data2<-rep(dat[1,],dat[3,])

# results
01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00
30       44       2
```

If you have any input of what I'm missing, I will be glad to listen.

Best.

Comment: side note: see this on how to [change language error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r)

Comment: Why `rep`? What is your expected output? Would `as.data.frame(t(data))` answer your question?

Comment: Hi Flodel,

rep is working fine with the 2 lines things as shown here `data1<-rep(dat[1,],dat[2,])`

`# results

01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00
15       80       67
`
I will try your method

Comment: Hi Flodel, not perfect but I can use a reshape afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: No, `rep` is for a totally different usage. You do not have a `dat` object but a `data` one. And `rep(data[1,],data[2,])` gives something totally different.

Comment: What you need to realize is that 1) you have data of different types, (strings or dates, integers) 2) R's objects for this kind of data are data.frames 3) data.frames are column wise objects where each column holds a different type of object. So you should store the transpose of your data in a data.frame. Easiest would be if the process creating your csv could store its transpose instead, and with a header, so you would only have to use `read.csv` on it.

Comment: `dat` is the name of my variable. I agree with you that I have `data` here. My aim was to have one hour (e.g 1AM) for one column and on the next row in the same column, the number of registrations. And that goes on for the next column ...

Comment: flodel, this is what I've done firsthand, have a CSV with a header but alas it did not work. This is why I've done it that way.

Time consuming, yes.  

Could have done through another way. yes.

But I'm learning : )

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind writing to a file in between, this would be the simplest way:

```
tmp <- read.table(text=textus)

write.table(t(tmp), "tmp.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

read.table("tmp.csv", sep = ",")
#         V1 V2 V3
# 1 01:00:00 15 30
# 2 02:00:00 80 44
# 3 03:00:00 67  2
```

There is no reason to have this transposed (as in the input file) in R. R's data.frame structure is designed to have variables in columns and observations in rows and most functions are optimized for this. If you just want to have it printed in the transposed form you should modify `print.data.frame`.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for your answer. You said that good practice mean that variables are in columns and observations in rows. 

However, when I'm plotting in such a way, I'm not having a plot with 2 curves. And my aim, is to have a plot.

If you have any insights about best pratices, I'm wiling to hear.

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: There are numerous possibilities to plot the data. `matplot(as.POSIXct(df[,1], format="%H:%M:%S"), df[,-1], type="l")` should get you started. Read some introductions to R in general and to plotting with R specifically.

Comment: Ok ... never heard of that one and did not know you could do that ... (baffled) and suddenly feeling very lame and not knowledgeable ...

Comment: @AndyK Yes, Grasshopper, knowing that you do not know is the first step on the path to enlightenment.  :-)  .    So go do the reading and experiment with different packages and functions;  you'll get the hang of it pretty soon.