# Mean function in R (Dealing with factors)

Tags: r

So I have this vector:

```
x
 [1] 76 89 78 50 84 56 29 53 32 68
112 Levels: 0 1 10 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 11 110 12 13 ... eta
```

why this happens?

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : l'argomento non è numerico o logico: restituisco NA
```

Comment: Trying to translate the error message: "the argument is neither numerical nor logical. Replaced with N/A".

Comment: You can set the language to English using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-the-language-of-errors-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `x` is a factor. There is a gotcha when converting factors to numbers. You need to use:

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you don't convert to character first, you will get the underlying factor codes.

Comment: Holy #### that indeed is a gotcha! Two thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `x` is a categorical variable -- try

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

(as per James pointing out that without `as.character`, you get factor codes:

```
x <- as.factor(10:20)
as.numeric(x)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Leaving out `na.rm=TRUE` since, while safer, it wasn't causing the problem)

Comment: Thanks! How do I know if I'm dealing with categorical or numerical variables?

Comment: What gave it away was that printing `x` gave you levels.  `R` usually parses "numberish" things into numerical variables, but I would guess that this vector was sliced a bit to get rid of some of them.  If you inspect the original vector, I bet you'd find something that isn't "numberish".

Comment: Use `str(your_object)` to see what mode things are stored in.

Comment: Indeed I thought that something not "numberish" might be hiding on the dataset but I have no clue how to locate it.

Comment: Haven't seen your data set, but you can play around with `> test <- as.data.frame(c(1:10, "foo"))`, which will load the one column as a categorical variable.  Even once you get rid of the last row (`test[,1:10]`), it will remain categorical.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an easy way to locate non numeric data in a huge vector. Anyway thx for the help!

Comment: Try `x[is.na(as.numeric(x))]`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing to numeric values, when you use the `mean` function, make sure you specify `na.rm=TRUE` in case you have `NA` values in the vector. Otherwise, it shows the warning you saw.