# Loading of RcppArmadillo package failed, even after an installation of RcppArmadillo packages from source that pass the loading test

Tags: r, macos, installation, package

Even after an installation of `RcppArmadillo` package from source that passes the loading test (version 0.5.200.1.0, R 3.1, mac OS mavericks), the loading of `RcppArmadillo` failed.

Did someone has already faced this problem and have any idea for fixing it?

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/RcppArmadillo_0.5.200.1.0-2.tar", repos = NULL,type='source')
* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
* checking LAPACK_LIBS: divide-and-conquer complex SVD available via R-supplied LAPACK
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RcppArmadillo)

library(RcppArmadillo)
```

> Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt
>   De plus : Message d'avis :
>   In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
>   Erreur : le chargement du package ou de l'espace de noms a échoué pour ‘RcppArmadillo’

Comment: Please provide error messages in English: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13575180/1412059 Btw., that would be a sensible setting anyway, because websearches for error messages are more successful of you search for the English message.

Comment: 3rd line: "package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked". Error message: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’"