# Manipulate strings from web-scraped data

Tags: r, string, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the data from a [webpage](http://perspective.usherbrooke.ca/bilan/servlet/BMTendanceStatPays?langue=fr&codePays=NOR&codeTheme=1&codeStat=SP.POP.TOTL) and I have trouble manipulating the strings. If you visit [the page](http://perspective.usherbrooke.ca/bilan/servlet/BMTendanceStatPays?langue=fr&codePays=NOR&codeTheme=1&codeStat=SP.POP.TOTL), you'll realize that this is a website written in French. I am trying to get the data in tabular format at the bottom of the page. In French, thousand separators are either `.` or `spaces`, which are used on [the webpage](http://perspective.usherbrooke.ca/bilan/servlet/BMTendanceStatPays?langue=fr&codePays=NOR&codeTheme=1&codeStat=SP.POP.TOTL).

Here is my code to scrap the values in the second column:

```
library(rvest)

link <- read_html("http://perspective.usherbrooke.ca/bilan/servlet/BMTendanceStatPays?langue=fr&codePays=NOR&codeTheme=1&codeStat=SP.POP.TOTL")

link %>%
   html_nodes(".tableauBarreDroite") %>%
   html_text() -> pop

head(pop)
[1] "3Â 581Â 239" "3Â 609Â 800" "3Â 638Â 918" "3Â 666Â 537" "3Â 694Â 339" "3Â 723Â 168"
```

The values in the `pop` vector contain the expected `spaces` with the unexpected `Â`. I tried the following to remove the `spaces`:

```
new.pop <- gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "", x = pop)

head(new.pop)
[1] "3Â 581Â 239" "3Â 609Â 800" "3Â 638Â 918" "3Â 666Â 537" "3Â 694Â 339" "3Â 723Â 168"
```

The `spaces` are still present in the `new.pop` variable. I also tried to remove tabs instead:

```
new.pop <- gsub(pattern = "\n", replacement = "", x = pop)

head(new.pop)
[1] "3Â 581Â 239" "3Â 609Â 800" "3Â 638Â 918" "3Â 666Â 537" "3Â 694Â 339" "3Â 723Â 168"
```

As you can see, the `spaces` are not going away. Do you have any idea what I should do to transform `pop` vector into a numeric vector after removing the unwanted characters?

Comment: Looks like a language/locale issue: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a tip, you should use this:

```
gsub(pattern="\\s",replacement="",x=pop) or
gsub(pattern=".\\s",replacement="@",x=pop)
```

because space is a special character.

Best,

Robert

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. `\s` is the regular expression for whitespace, right? What about `@`?

Comment: Also, how could I remove both the `whitespace` and the `Â` character in the same `gsub` call? I tried `gsub("[\\sÂ]", "", pop)`, but it did not work. It only removed the `Â` character.

Comment: this should remove the Â and the whitespace:

gsub(pattern=".\\s",replacement="@",x=pop)