# Removing special characters from factor and converting to numeric in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I need to convert a messy factor into a numeric. The sample data looks like this:

```
x <- structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L), 
    .Label = c("", "106", "39", "8", "80", "chyb\x92 foto"), class = "factor")
```

My desired output would be:

```
x
[1]   8  80  NA  NA  NA 106  39
class(x)
"numeric"
```

However, the first line of my intended code results in a warning and the text is not replaced with `NAs`.

```
x[grepl("[a-z]", x) | x==""] <- NA
x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In grepl("[a-z]", x) : input string 4 is invalid in this locale
>   2: In grepl("[a-z]", x) : input string 5 is invalid in this locale

The second line then runs correctly and provides the correct output with `NAs` introduced by coercion. Why does `grepl` fail to recognise letters in some factor levels, and how can `as.numeric` pick them out and replace them with `NAs`?

The factor to numeric conversion was chosen from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/5967807). However, the fact that it works does not answer my question why.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8/C/cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0
```

Comment: grep takes the integer part of the factor (the vector), not the levels. Maybe read `?factor` ?

Comment: I get the desired output with your lines, without the warnings

Comment: @Tensibai I don't thing the factor is the problem. `grepl("a-z", levels(x))` generates the same warning.

Comment: I don't get a warning with that line so probably there is something you're not telling us (maybe try your example and your lines in a fresh session) and/or you should give us your sessionInfo

Comment: @Cath I added the sessionInfo. The warning persist with the fresh run.

Comment: @Tensibai Tried. Problem not solved. Note that my `grepl` pattern already is as you suggest.

Comment: @nya seems the problem comes  from `"chyb\x92 foto"`, what does it print if you do `t<-"chyb\x92 foto";print(t)` (for me the \x92 is a single quote) ?

Comment: @Tensibai `[1] "chyb\x92 foto"` In the original csv file, the text reads "chybí foto".

Comment: @nya ok so we get the cause (more or less), now the why seems to be an invalid char in Czech locale

Comment: One more question: could you add the results of `Encoding(levels(x))` ? (And maybe `levels(x) <- enc2utf8(levels(x))` could solve the problem)

Comment: @Tensibai Thank you, that solved the `grepl` issue. I added my current understanding of the problem as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found the solution. Thanks to akrun, Cath and Tensibai for pointing me towards `Encoding`. My `levels(x)` were encoded as "unknown", for which `grepl` found values with text when it was instructed to read `bytes`:

```
grepl("[a-z]", x, useBytes = TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Tensibar's suggestion to specify the encoding provides identical functionality for `grepl`.

```
levels(x) <- enc2utf8(levels(x))
grepl("[a-z]", x, useBytes = FALSE)
```

Unlike complex ability of `grepl` to deal with accented characters and various encoding, `as.numeric` takes an object and finds if it can be interpretable as a number. Which any text, regardless of encoding, is not.

Using `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` for factor conversion might be a safe method to use by itself without the need to check for problematic values first.

Answer (score 1):

We can just do

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
#[1]   8  80  NA  NA  NA 106  39
```

---

If we are using `grepl`, we will make sure that we are only finding the numeric part from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string and negate (`!`) it and then assign those values to NA.  As 'x' is a `factor`, we can convert to `numeric` by `as.numeric(as.character`.

```
 x[!grepl("^[0-9.]+$", x)] <- NA
 as.numeric(as.character(x))
 #[1]   8  80  NA  NA  NA 106  39
```

Comment: Yes. But why cannot `grepl` find cells with text?

Comment: @nya It got dupe tagged.  Please check if that works for you or else we can reopen can I will answer that part

Comment: Absolutely not. My code `x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` solves the conversion as well as your answer. My question is why `grepl` fails where `as.numeric` succeeds?

Comment: @nya I added the `grepl` part

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives me the "input string is invalid in this locale" warning.

Comment: @nya Using your example, I am not getting the warning with R 3.3.0.  Probably, you need to change the settings to have utf-8 characters

Comment: @nya You can check the `sessionInfo()` .  For the locale, I have `locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`

Comment: I added the sessionInto to the question. In essence, I wish to remove all text, including any accented characters.

Comment: @nya You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r) for changing the locale