# After I installed car package, I can not load Salaries data set

Tags: r

```
 > r#quire(car)        # Salaries 데이타을 사용을 위해
    필요한 패키지를 로딩중입니다: car
    Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
      네임스페이스 ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2는 로드되었으나 >= 0.4.4가 필요합니다
    In addition: Warning message:
    패키지 ‘car’는 R 버전 3.2.5에서 작성되었습니다 
    > library(car)
    Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
      네임스페이스 ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2는 로드되었으나 >= 0.4.4가 필요합니다
    In addition: Warning message:
    패키지 ‘car’는 R 버전 3.2.5에서 작성되었습니다 
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’
    > str(Salaries)
    Error in str(Salaries) : object 'Salaries' not found
```

A car package is the default one it already installed when  I install r. I tried to download and include it. But It still got the error that it can not find the Salaries data set that included in car package. What is the problem?  Sorry for the Korean message. If you let me know to change message in English, I will retry and reupload the message.  Below is my console

---

UPDATE

I updated this error message in English and tried running the comment's one. But still it is not working.

```
> install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/car_2.1-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1447199 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Windows\Temp\Rtmpgr6B80\downloaded_packages
> library(car)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.4 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’
> str(Salaries)
Error in str(Salaries) : object 'Salaries' not found
```

Comment: I think you need to install the package `pbkrtest`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13575180/1412059

Comment: `install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It solved with update r version up to 3.3.2. pbkrtest needs r version  to be more than 3.3.2 (newest version). I updated r and reinstall pbkrtest and then car package.

Answer (score 1):

Salaries data set is currently available under [`carData` package], I solved as the following

```
install.packages("carData")

data("Salaries", package="carData")

sample_n(Salaries,3)
       rank discipline yrs.since.phd yrs.service  sex salary
1      Prof          B            26          19 Male 193000
2 AssocProf          A            13           8 Male  78182
3  AsstProf          B             4           3 Male  91000
```