# I got different language result in r

Tags: r, format

If I write code like

```
everyday = seq(from=as.Date('2005-1-1'), to=as.Date('2005-12-31'), by='day') 
cmonth = format(everyday, '%B')
table(cmonth)
cmonth
10월 11월 12월  1월  2월  3월  4월  5월  6월  7월  8월  9월 
31   30   31   31   28   31   30   31   30   31   31   30
```

I get result in korean, but i want

```
October November December January February March ...
```

like this in eng. how can i change that

Comment: Perhaps you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r)

Comment: change your locale *or* get the month numbers and use them as indices to the built-in `month.name` object

Comment: changing locale works! Thanks :)