# How can I install Rstudio in german?

Tags: r, rstudio

guys

OS: Windows 7(basic language: Korean)

I installed 'R' in German. (it is cleared)

but when I install 'R studio', I couldn't select any other option(language)

So, my question is..

1. How can I use 'R studio' in German??
2. (If you wanna explain about R console, I already did it. but, it didn't work.)
   ex. language = en
   is there German code? (de? gr? ge? and so on.)

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660007-Changing-Language-in-R-studio ???