# Set R Services error messages language on SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server instance with default language is English

But when I execute R scripts on SQL Server (R Services is installed as standalone server on the same machine), I got error messages including Turkish (from R services)

SQL Engine messages are in English

So I want to know if it is possible and how to change the language of R Services installed with SQL Server

Thanks for any help

Comment: This might helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r

Comment: Thanks alot, help me a lot. I change the session language so I got errors in English