# *platform-independent* language/locale settings?

Tags: r, locale, error-messaging

### tl;dr

Is it possible to change the `LANGUAGE` environment setting (or the `LC_MESSAGES` component of the locale) **platform-independently**, and if not (which is probably the case) to detect whether the value requested was in fact legal/took effect?

### Context

One of my functions tried to detect the occurrence of a particular error by `grep()`ing the text of the error message. As previously pointed on an R mailing list (can't find the reference right now), this approach is fragile: the text of the message can change based on the setting of the `LANGUAGE` environment variable.

So I'm changing my code to not do that, but I'd like to add a regression test to the package that tests whether the problem occurs. And I'd like it to work (or at least not fail) across platforms.

As described e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r), I can use `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE=...)` or `Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES",.)` to change the message language.  But this will only work if I guess the right `LANGUAGE`/`LC_MESSAGES` value, and it's available on the current system. (It seems that `LANGUAGE` is a language code, and `LC_MESSAGES` is a locale, and that *the locale need not be installed* if I just want to switch languages?)

```
Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE") ## [1] "en_CA:en"
test_msg <- function(msg,silent=FALSE) {
   grepl(msg,try(x ,silent=silent))
}
test_msg("not found") ## TRUE ("object 'x' not found")
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="fr")
test_msg("introuvable")
## Erreur : objet 'x' introuvable
```

So far, so good. But resetting the `LANGUAGE` variable doesn't seem to work ...

```
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")=="en" ## TRUE
test_msg("not found")   ## FALSE ('introuvable')
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en_CA:en")
test_msg("not found") ## FALSE ('introuvable')
```

Setting `LC_MESSAGES` to C seems more reliable ...

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "C")
test_msg("not found")
```

FWIW I've found that this sequence of commands actually seems to be *unreliable*, i.e. the same attempt to set the environment variable seems to work *sometimes* depending on what pissing around I've done previously ... I have to go back and keep starting with a clean session to get reproducible results ...

In any case, I know that if I were to try this on a computer without a French locale available, or where the locale/language name was different, that it wouldn't work. I'd like to be able to figure out whether the language setting has worked. I can use `test_msg("introuvable")` as brute force, but I'm hoping there's  a more elegant option ...

---

relevant bits of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R Under development (unstable) (2018-11-26 r75681)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
    
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF8
```

Comment: Not sure this helps but ... I can report that on my computer, running Windows 7 and R 3.5.1, resetting `LANGUAGE` as in your second block **does** work. On the other hand, running `Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "C")`, as in your 3rd block, gives me a couple of warning messages that: (1) `LC_MESSAGES exists on Windows but is not operational`; and (2) `OS reports request to set locale to "C" cannot be honored`.