# How can I change the language of the IDE RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

How can I change the language of RStudio? I mean the menu and not the messages or R itself as described here: [How to change language settings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r)

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660007-Changing-Language-in-R-studio

Comment: RStudio has their own website for support questions: https://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio does not exist in other languages:

> The RStudio IDE is currently not localized into other languages, so
>   will remain in English even if you change the system settings. Is that
>   what you were asking?

Answer from RStudio employee [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-changing-the-language-in-rstudio/5382/4).