# How to get RStudio to use R language settings?

Tags: r, user-interface, rstudio, settings

To set the **R** language to English we add `language = EN` to the `Rconsole` file in the `~\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\` folder as e.g. described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674852/6574038). This works as expected for the **R GUI**.

However, **RStudio** seems to ignore **R** language settings and starts up with the language of my system locale. I'm using `Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`, `R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)` and `RStudio Version 1.2.5019`.

[image]

There are a lot of answers that confuse **R GUI** and **RStudio**. How can we get **RStudio** to use the language settings defined in the `Rconsole` file? (Or, alternatively, where can we set the language for **RStudio** seperately?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that works only if you want English, is to suppress the translation files.

An easy way to proceed is to uninstall R and then reinstall R without the translation files. So be sure to chose customize installation and to unselect the translation files during installation.

Comment: Simple and efficient, thank you @Gilbert! I finally implemented this, when I updated to version `3.6.3`!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but it may have to do with the actual versions of RStudio (1.2.5019, 1.2.5033) With these I have the same problem (Windows 7pro/64, R 3.6.1). With the older RStudio version 1.2.5001, this problem does not exist.

addition as of Jan 6 2019:

I eventually seem to have figured out a solution to this problem. As pointed out by alberto in his answer to question in another context (see
[How to change the locale of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r)), you have to edit your Renviron.site file such that it contains the line

LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"

or, if you prefer R with British accent

LANGUAGE = "en_GB.utf8"

You may find your Renviron file in your R intallation folder, subfolder "etc".

Note that in a fresh installation of R, there is no file "Renviron.site". Then, just create it with a text editor.

Including in your Rcolsole file the line

language = en

may also help, though it is not sufficient.

Note the different use of Capitals and "" in Renviron and Rconsole.

You have t restart R after you modified/created Renviron.

Comment: Such kind of answers are better posted as a comment here on SO. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and on questions.