# Non-english letters in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a problem with handling non english letters in data frame. I want to change the column names, but function `dplyr::rename(colName1 = śśś)` shows error and informs that this column does not exist.

This is just example. I know, I could rename the columns in different way.

I tried to change default encoding in global options to UTF-8 however it doesn't help.

Comment: This works for me ```tibble(śśś = "") %>% dplyr::rename(colName1 = śśś)```. Try ```colnames(df)``` and add it here. There may be whitespace in the name.

Comment: can you share the output of dput(head(df)) for better reproducibility?

Comment: @NirbhaySingh Ok, so this helped to localize the problem. the output shows `sss`.I tried to create mock df but still nonEnglish characters are converted into english.  So as  I understand the R do not process nonenglish letters in this case. (The previous df was from imported .csv). I guess I should update language pack but don't exactly know how to do it.

Comment: @haphap32 this might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what the problem is. If what you want is to change a non-ASCII column name into an ASCII name you can do that by matching the non-ASCII name with regex:

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  NY = c("some", "data", "more", "data"),
  śśś = c("some", "data", "more", "data")
)
```

To change the non-ASCII name to, say, `Whatever`, use `grepl` to match `[^ -~]`, a character class (`[...]`) to **exclude** (`^`) any ASCII character (`-~`) and thus match non-ASCII characters such as, for example, `ś` but also Greek letters, Chinese characters, Arabic letters, Umlaut, and so on:

```
colnames(df)[grepl("[^ -~]", colnames(df))] <- "Whatever"
```

Result:

```
df
    NY Whatever
1 some     some
2 data     data
3 more     more
4 data     data
```