# How do I set R console's language to English using a configuration file?

Tags: r

I am trying to set my R console's language to English using a configuration file. I am using Debian and Ubuntu as my OS. To set the R console's language to English, I created `~/.Renviron` containing:

```
LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

This works, but I only found it through trial and error, so I am concerned that this will break if I change my system's default languages and locales in the future. These are my current system's environment variables:

```sh
$ env | grep "LANG\|LC_"                                                           
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8:zh_CN.UTF-8:en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_SG.UTF-8
```

I want to make sure that no matter what my future system's `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, `LC_*` are going to be, the values in `~/.Renviron` will ensure that the R console's language is English. How can I do that? Does my current `~/.Renviron` achieve this goal?

In other words, is setting `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8` in `~/.Renviron` sufficient to guarantee that the R console's language is always English no matter what my system's default languages and locales become in the future?

I've read this: [How to change language settings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r), but the answers there do not use a configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does my current `~/.Renviron` achieve this goal?

Probably yes, but potentially not quite.

The relevant information can be found in the [`locales` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html):

> The following categories should always be supported: `"LC_ALL"`, `"LC_COLLATE"`, `"LC_CTYPE"`, `"LC_MONETARY"`, `"LC_NUMERIC"` and `"LC_TIME"`. Some systems (not Windows) will also support `"LC_MESSAGES"`, `"LC_PAPER"` and `"LC_MEASUREMENT"`. […]
>
> Note that setting category `"LC_ALL"` sets only categories `"LC_COLLATE"`, `"LC_CTYPE"`, `"LC_MONETARY"` and `"LC_TIME"`. […]
>
> Note that the `LANGUAGE` environment variable has precedence over `"LC_MESSAGES"` in selecting the language for message translation on most R platforms.

So you might want to also set those categories not set by `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE`:

- `LC_NUMERIC`
- `LC_PAPER`
- `LC_MEASUREMENT`

Lastly, the [R “Startup” documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) tells us that using `~/.Renviron` is a good place to set these:

> Unless `--no-environ` was given on the command line, R searches for site and user files to process for setting environment variables. […] The name of the user file can be specified by the `R_ENVIRON_USER` environment variable; if this is unset, the files searched for are ‘`.Renviron`’ in the current or in the user's home directory (in that order).

Personally I prefer de-cluttering my home directory and putting all such configuration under `~/.config`, e.g. `~/.config/R/REnviron`. Doing so requires slightly more work, however, since R by default doesn’t respect the [XDG conventions](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html): to fix this I’m setting the environment variables `R_ENVIRON_USER`, `R_LIBS_USER` and `R_PROFILE_USER` in my `.bashrc`:

```sh
export R_ENVIRON_USER=$HOME/.config/R/Renviron

# Need to be set here rather than in REnviron so that they can be overridden
# temporarily:

export R_PROFILE_USER=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-$HOME/.config}/R/init.r
export R_LIBS_USER=${XDG_DATA_HOME-$HOME/.local/share}/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/%v
```