# Issue with input keyboard sources in RStudio Fedora 32

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, fedora, textinputlayout

My RStudio in Fedora 32 doesn't accept other input sources rather than the default en-US keyboard while other apps are doing well. I have to type Vietnamese letters in Text Editor and copy to RStudio. Does anyone have the same issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: I confirm I have the same on Fedora 32. If I switch to other languages in the Latin script, it works, but if switch e.g. to Cyrillic, it doesn't (while it works fine in other programmes)

Comment: To be more precise, it works with standard Cyriliic, but it doesn't when I use the translit option that build characters based on multiple inputs. I'd file a bug with Rstudio.

Comment: @giocomai Did older Fedora systems have the same issue? I've never used Linux before?

Comment: @giocomai Please give me the link that you file the bug.

Comment: I do occasionally use cyrillic, and I don't remember having this issue before and previous versions of Fedora, which I've been using for years. It could be related to the latest Fedora or the latest Rstudio, or the way Rstudio is packaged for Fedora. Perhaps uninstalling Rstudio from the repositories and using the RPM downloaded from the Rstudio site would work. Or downloading older Rstudio versions. You may give it a try. If it doesn't work, I'll try to check and file a bug in the coming days.

Comment: in the meantime, you may also give it a try on the Rstudio community forums, which are usually very welcoming, and may give you a response more quickly https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: for the records, I found out that on a second computer, with Fedora 32 and same version of Rstudio, I *do not* have this problem. I'm leaving this here just in case someone fails to replicate. Still trying to figure out where's the issue.

Comment: @giocomai I ended up using Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r) [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r)

Not sure if this will only change the displayed language, but I hope this would change the keyboard input as well. This also might be a Operating system setting, even though you said other programs work fine