# Changing language settings in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

How can I change permanently the language of error messages in R? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r) but I still don't get how to add the environment variable to the system.

Thanks a lot

Comment: OS, please? This is easier to answer if you tell us which of the solutions in the link you have tried and what failed.

Comment: You can add `LANG="fr"` (or whatever language) to [`.Renviron`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), or add `Sys.setenv(LANG="fr")` to `.Rprofile`, or export an environment variable in your OS outside of and before starting R. In windows, search for `environment` and you'll see `Edit the system environment variables`; in linux, add `export LANG="fr"` to one of your home/dot-bash files or etc/bash files; in macos ... I suspect it's the same as linux, but I don't know. A web search for `environment variable` (and your OS) will be very fruitful.

Comment: Windows10, thank you. I am speaking about Chase's solution with the `Sys.setenv()` function, which changes the language but only temporarily. I tried Alessandro Jacopson's solution as well but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try *my* comment? All of those are non-temporary, either R-only (`.Renviron` or `.Rprofile`) or all apps/terminal (user or system variables).

Comment: Thanks so much, I used `.Renviron` and it worked!