# R Console Language Setting

Tags: r

I am wondering if you can change R console language setting. My computer (MacBook Air)'s settings are all in English, but the R console language is in Korean. I found how to change the settings on Windows, but it didn't work on OS. Is there a way to change the R console language (such as error msgs) settings to English at all times?

Comment: When you run `sessionInfo()`, what is listed under "Locale"?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353147

Comment: hi, I tried  >system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8") in R console and it worked. Thank you so much! :)