# Using PCA with princomp or prcomp on MNIST data

Tags: r, pca, mnist

i want to reduce the dimension of the MNIST data to 45.

i use keras to import MNIST data

```
library(keras)
 
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
 
X <- mnist$train$x

Xreduced <- X / 255 

pcaX <- princomp(Xreduced) 

Xfinal <- as.matrix(Xreduced) %*% pcaX$loadings[,1:45]
```

this last line of code isnt running. i also tried "prcomp" instead of "printcomp" with same issue

error message says

> Error in pcaX$loadings[, 1:45] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: To change the language of console output use `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r  
Also, why 45 dimensions? What does your scree plot look like?

Comment: this code is from a university lecture where this code is shown, but doesnt run. as far as i know 45 is randomly selected, as it is never mentioned how this number is derived

Comment: and ofc thank you for your help with the language!

Comment: In that case your best option is to go back to your lecturer and ask why it isn't working - it's more likely a typo rather than an actual programming issue.