# R info and error and warning messages showing in Spanish for some reason... How to change back to English?

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings, non-english

I recently made a trip to Spain with my laptop, and ever since then, all R warnings and error messages show in Spanish. I don't recall having changed any settings at all.

This only happens in R, everything else shows properly in English.

I am on macOS Monterey using R version 4.1.2. Language & Region in my System Settings are correctly set to my current location and preferred language (English).

However, R still shows everything in Spanish... My `Sys.getlocale()` shows the following:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
```

See screenshot for the last error message I got trying some new code... when launching R, the main welcome message shows in Spanish too... Thanks!

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

[This question has been answered before in greater detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r) but in short, you can use `Sys.setenv()` and set `LANG = "en"`. This is a temporary solution but long-term solutions are in the link above. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the long term solution for mac in one of the answers in the link (`defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8`) but it does not seem to do anything for me