# The R console is in German language, how can I set R to English?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am using R on Windows 8. If I run R in RStudio, the console gives me the error messages in German. For a variety of reasons, this is undesirable, and I want R to be English.

I found the very same problem here:
[The R console is in my native language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760491/the-r-console-is-in-my-native-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english)

I did exactly as was suggested (changed "Language for non-Unicode programs" to English and rewrote the Rconsole file) but it didn't help.

Best regards

Comment: I have `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` in my Rprofile.site, which works just fine. Please don't combine separate issues in one question. I.e., your `savePlot` issue belongs in a new question.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit a new question for the saveplot issue in 90 minutes. Is there also a Profile.site file in RStudio? Did you just wrote a new line into the file with `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` ?

Comment: RStudio is just an IDE (the "frontend"). You are still using R (as the "backend") and there is an Rprofile.site file in `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\etc` (or whereever you have installed R).

Comment: Oh well, good point. It works perfectly now! Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is that when you install R you have the translate error messages already checked, next time you just have to avoid to download translation by not enabling this option

Comment: @BBrill Didn't know there was a translation option in the installation. But I will remember this for the next installation. Thanks for the help!