# R : language changes when converting ts object to xts object

Tags: r, time-series, settings, xts

I try to convert the built-in time series `sunspots` data into an xts object and print it out with the following code:

```
sunspots.xts <- as.xts(sunspots)
sunspots.xts
```

The result looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0snX.jpg)

And here is my `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7 zoo_1.7-14 timeDate_3012.100

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2 grid_3.3.2 lattice_0.20-34
```

The months are now written in traditional chinese but I want the output to remain in english. My R environment is completely in English. I guess somehow xts knows my operating system (win 8) to be working in traditional chinese and decides to change the expression of month into traditional chinese. There are similar discussions on the site and I have tried the following:

- adding language = en to the Rconsole file ([The R console is in my native language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760491/the-r-console-is-in-my-native-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english))
- changing "Language for non-Unicode programs" to english in the windows control   panel([The R console is in my native language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760491/the-r-console-is-in-my-native-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english))
- writing Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN") in my Rprofile.site file ([The R console is in German language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171235/the-r-console-is-in-german-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english))

None of them works. I think it's because the question is somehow different. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Can you please edit a sample of the data into your question? Pictures of data are not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you for the reply. The output of sessionInfo():
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 LC_NUMERIC=C                                
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950

Comment: attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-14        timeDate_3012.100

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2     grid_3.3.2      lattice_0.20-34

Comment: @Joshua: Thank you. I am not sure if I understand you correctly. It is the preloaded time series data set in R called sunspots. You could view it by writing sunspots().

Comment: You need to change your locale settings. See `help("Sys.setlocale")`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Roland commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626581/r-language-changes-when-converting-ts-object-to-xts-object?noredirect=1#comment72611762_42626581), you need to change your locale settings.  If you change `LC_TIME` to `"C"` the times will print in English.

```
# Save current LC_TIME
def.locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")

# Set LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "ja_JP.UTF-8")
sunspots.xts <- as.xts(sunspots)
head(sunspots.xts)
#           [,1]
#  1月 1749 58.0
#  2月 1749 62.6
#  3月 1749 70.0
#  4月 1749 55.7
#  5月 1749 85.0
#  6月 1749 83.5

# Set LC_TIME=C
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "C")
head(sunspots.xts)
#          [,1]
# Jan 1749 58.0
# Feb 1749 62.6
# Mar 1749 70.0
# Apr 1749 55.7
# May 1749 85.0
# Jun 1749 83.5

# Set locale back
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = def.locale)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed instruction. It works now.