# Very simple : as.Date error with August

Tags: r

I'm trying to use as.Date with some data, but I encounter NAs with specific months. I created a data.frame named Fake to test it, and it gave me the same error : it works with September but not with August.

```
Fake <- c("Sep 12 2014", "Aug 12 2014")
as.Date(Fake, format ="%b %d %Y")
```

This is what I get:

```
> as.Date(Fake, format ="%b %d %Y")
[1] "2014-09-12" NA
```

I need to use June data also but it doesn't work, even if July data does. Anyone can help?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. What's your `R.version.string`? Mine is `[1] "R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)"`.

Comment: I have this one -> $version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)" How can I get the one you have?

Comment: Oh, it might be [locale](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) related. What's your `Sys.getlocale()`? (Mine is `[1] "en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8/C/en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8"`.)

Comment: @Evenlyne1991, you can upgrade to the latest R version, but since you're already using a quite recent version, that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Also, can you run `strftime(sprintf('2015-%02d-01',1:12),format='%b')` and show me the output? (Mine is `[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"`.)

Comment: fr_CA.UTF-8/fr_CA.UTF-8/fr_CA.UTF-8/C/fr_CA.UTF-8/fr_CA.UTF-8 for the locale. And THAT'S IT -> > strftime(sprintf('2015-%02d-01',1:12),format='%b')
 [1] "jan" "fév" "mar" "avr" "mai" "jui" "jul" "aoû" "sep" "oct" "nov" "déc"  (Obviously this is the problem because I am a French speaker using a French R Studio... but how can I get the English one?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have a French locale, which uses different month and day names and abbreviations. You can change to the English locale by running:

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','en_CA.utf-8');
```

**Edit:** You might also/instead have to run this (I've found this to be necessary in RStudio):

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','English');
```

References that might be useful to people:

- [How to change the locale of R in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r-in-rstudio)
- [The R console is in my native language, how can I set R to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760491/the-r-console-is-in-my-native-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english)

Comment: Except... it still doesn't work -_- '  > strftime(sprintf('2015-%02d-01',1:12),format='%b')
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
> Fake <- c("Sep 12 2014", "Aug 12 2014")
> as.Date(Fake, format ="%b %d %Y")
[1] "2014-09-12" NA

Comment: Hmm, can you run `unname(sapply(c('LC_ALL','LC_COLLATE','LC_CTYPE','LC_MONETARY','LC_NUMERIC','LC_TIME'), Sys.getlocale ))` and show me the output? (Mine is `[1] "en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8/C/en_CA.utf-8/en_CA.utf-8" "en_CA.utf-8" "en_CA.utf-8" "en_CA.utf-8" "C" "en_CA.utf-8"`.)

Comment: I can't read the symbol in : LC‌​_TIM after the "LC", it doesn't give anything in my console.

Comment: I know! This is very strange. I think there might be something wrong on Stack Overflow's end here. When we copy the text out of the comment, there are [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) and [zero-width non-joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200C/index.htm) characters embedded after the LC in LC_TIME. I can't seem to get rid of them, no matter how I try to edit the comment. You're going to have to manually type out the remainder of the code, starting from the C in LC_TIME.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74219/discussion-between-evelyne1991-and-bgoldst).

Answer (score 1):

You should open try opening your terminal and run the following command in the prompt :

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

Then relaunch R or RStudio and try running your code again. Everything should work.
If you need further information you can check this blog :

http://mito.air-nifty.com/mitoakiyoshiblog/2010/03/how-to-change-l.html