# from week of day to date

Tags: r

I have a character vector

```
x=c("Thu Jan 30 2020")
```

when I use function as.Date in `base` package as follows, it returns NA.

```
as.Date(x,format="%a %b %d %Y")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works for me. Check your locale: %a and %b  are **locale-specific**.  What is the result of `Sys.getlocale()`  (specifically `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` ?)

Comment: You need to change the R/R Studio to English. To do that try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760491/the-r-console-is-in-my-native-language-how-can-i-set-r-to-english or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575180/how-to-change-language-settings-in-r

Comment: I got> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "Korean_Korea.949" and solved it by
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English") Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A hard-coding workaround

```
s <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[c(4, 2, 3)]
as.Date(paste0(
  replace(
    s,
    2,
    sprintf("%02d", match(s[2], month.abb))
  ),
  collapse = "-"
))
```